# existence of space and deformation retraction

Tags: algebraic-topology

Consider a homotopy equivalence between two non-empty topological spaces $M$ and $N$.

Prove there exist a topological space P and inclusions $i : M → P,\  j : N → P$  such that $i(M ) ⊂ P, \ j(N ) ⊂ P$ are deformation retraction.

I think of the obvious direct product $P=M\times N$. Would it be a good start to tackle this question?

Thank you!

Comment: Thank for your example, but I think that $\pi_1(S^1,-) \cong \Bbb Z \not \cong \pi_1(S^2,-) \cong \{1\} $ and this is a condition in my question?

Comment: Try $M=N=S^1$. Although the circles are retracts of the torus (the product $M\times N$), they're not deformation retracts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instead $M_f$, the mapping cyllinder for a homotopy equivalence $f:M \to N$. This is $(M  \times I) \coprod N/\sim$ where $(m,1) \sim f(m)$.

Note that this retracts onto $N$  by just going along $(x,t)$. How about $M$? See Hatcher Chapter 0 for how this all goes.

Comment: Thank you Andres! corollary 0.21 in Hatcher. I didn't understand the proof though:

- if $r$ is the canonical retraction, why it is a homotopy equivalence?

- why the inclusion $j$ is a homotopy equivalence?